# Cant start Host machine in one go, have to restart two to three times after installing the KVM with gpu passthrough

Tags: nvidia, intel, qemu, kvm

I've been encountering an issue while setting up GPU passthrough on my host machine, and here what I have setup:

- BIOS Settings: I have ensured that the IOMMU feature is enabled in my system's BIOS. It's labeled as "VT-d" (Intel) in my BIOS, and it's turned on.
- Kernel Parameters: In my GRUB configuration, I have added the intel_iommu=on iommu=pt video=efifb:off parameters. I verified that they are consistently applied across the system.
- Module Loading: The modules vfio_pci vfio vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_virqfd loaded during the boot process. I checked the output of lsmod and the system log files, and there are no apparent errors related to module loading.
- GPU Configuration: I have created the file /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf with the correct GPU IDs specified as options vfio-pci ids=8086:1901,10de:1f91,10de:10fa and blacklist i2c_nvidia_gpu. I double-checked for any typos or errors in the configuration file.

Despite following these steps, my host machine does not boot reliably on the first try. It takes several reboots before successfully booting into the host machine and I am also encountering the freezing issues after successfully turned off the Windows 10 VM with GPU passthrough, and restarting the VM again will freeze the host machine.

Have any of you encountered a similar problem with GPU passthrough? Are there any additional steps I should take or factors I should consider?

Hardware Specifications:

```
Laptop: Asus ROG G531GT

CPU: i5 9th gen 9300H

GPU: Geforce GTX 1650 4gb
```

Software Specifications:

```
Linux Distribution: manjaro latest

Kernel Version: 6.2.16-2-MANJARO

GPU Driver Version: nvidia 525 proprietary driver
```

Here is the error from the dmesg:

```
[   19.207228] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 509
[   19.207234] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
[   19.208077] NVRM: This can occur when a driver such as: 
               NVRM: nouveau, rivafb, nvidiafb or rivatv 
               NVRM: was loaded and obtained ownership of the NVIDIA device(s).
[   19.208078] NVRM: Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or
               NVRM: reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting
               NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
               NVRM: again.
[   19.208080] NVRM: No NVIDIA devices probed.
[   19.208259] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered Nvlink Core, major device number 509
[   20.704846] systemd-journald[264]: File /var/log/journal/0bfc93c760624629a79c9d417cb1de2b/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
```

Some edited file regarding the GPU passthru:

```
# cat /etc/default/grub                                                                                        
# GRUB boot loader configuration

GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Manjaro"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=on iommu=pt video=efifb:off resume=UUID=2471ee83-7eb1-4ec5-9897-e7636cbef5a3 udev.log_priority=3"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# cat /etc/mkinitcpio.conf 
MODULES="vfio_pci vfio vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_virqfd"

# cat /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf                                                                                
blacklist i2c_nvidia_gpu
options vfio-pci ids=8086:1901,10de:1f91,10de:10fa

# cat /etc/modules-load.d/vfio.conf                                                                            
vendor-reset
```

VM.xml: https://pastebin.com/NsnpE5pK

Error Dmesg:
r/VFIO - Issue with Reliable Booting and Freezing after VM Restart with GPU Passthrough

error dmesg:
[image: error dmesg]

I want to setup a proper GPU passthrough to windows 10 or 11 VM and It doesn't have to break the after every reboot of host machine. I want to solve the problem of reliable boot up means that after successfully shutdown of the host machine and restarting again, It wont restart in one go. I have to reboot it several times to boot into the machine. And after successfully passthrough the GPU to win10 VM and shutdown and reboot the guest system, freezes the whole host machine.